# "Domesticating" microbes

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, xenobiology

I wanna know more about the plausibility of a creature having the ability to "domesticate" foreign cells.

For example: a lizard with mouth infections bites my leg and the creature manages to run away, the infection does not kill me, instead my body finds a way to make the bacteria work for me in some way or another and not just becoming immune to it.

What tries to attack the creature makes it stronger (or at least becomes a harmless symbiont) in a way or another, if it survives.

Comment: Your creature would have to become a nursery for the invading cells.

Comment: I'm not sure what the real spirit of the question is. We as humans have "domesticated" lots of bacteria that have established stable relationships with us to the point humans are a virtual ecosystem. Are you talking about gaining some sort of super-power like being bitten by a radioactive spider? Maybe with some already specialized bacteria, but I don't think it would be us that causes it - it would be the bacteria.

Comment: Just to note that we humans did domesticate unicellular lifeforms. All sing in praise of [*Saccharomyces cerevisiae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae), [*Lactobacillus bulgaricus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactobacillus_delbrueckii_subsp._bulgaricus), and [*Acetobacter aceti*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetobacter_aceti).

Comment: Ad: super yogurt comes with billions of good bacteria...

Comment: @AlexP: Not to mention our entire internal microbiome, largely domesticated long before our ancestors evolved to be even remotely human. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_microbiome

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry, but I don't think this ability is biologicaly plausible. There are some cases of symbiotic relationships as you want to get, but none of them developed as instantly on first contact as you suggest it. The main problem is, bacteria are not intelligent, they are unicellular lifeforms and they 'do what they do'. Your body is not able to get them doing other things as those they are build for to do, you can't even get them to do these things 'your way' (without bioengeneering or long time 'breeding' them of course). So for bring your desired ability to action, your body should be able to detect this bacteria, analyse what it does exactly, needs to find a way to use it for your own interests, transport it to the place where it is needed and contain in there while getting immune to its negative effects. Event the first (detection) and the last (immunization) points are problems for a body with first contact to a hostile bacteria, not to mention the high difficulties of the other steps. So no, instantly this will not be plausible, symbiotic relationships are more like a long-term evolution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, simply having a stronger immune system sounds like a better (and pore plausible) solution.

Let's go with your example: a lizard bites your and now the wound is riddled with bacteria. Their goal? To eat and multiply, so your creature somehow rewires them to...? The bacteria infecting your wound have the purpose to feed on whatever organic material they find and multiply, so even if they have something like [CRISPR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRISPR) on them, they will hardly be useful enough to your creature to be worth keeping.

It is true that bacteria might have some mechanisms that could seem useful to you, but for these bacteria to exist within your body without being targeted by your immune system, they'd have to be converted into cells with a signature much like your own. That could most likely result in problems, should one of these bacteria, which are now invisible to your immune system, suffer a genetic mutation (which is very common among prochariotic cells) and suddenly start seizing nutrients and multiplying uncontrollably in a cancerous fashion (remember you're trying to make procariotic cells, which most of the time aren't used to being part of a multicellular organism, to function similarly to your own euchariotic cells and somehow not cause problems despite usually having a different genome).

A more effective way would be to simply have a more effective immune system, since it's very function is to ensure that things that are attacking you become harmless by eliminating them. It's a widespread mechanism, seems to work pretty well and most of the time doesn't create a problem of multiple different cells that are not an active part of your body to remain in it, potentially becoming problem later (a good example lies in your digestive track. In it lie multiple kinds of bacteria that are beneficial to us, but in cases of low immunity, some of these bacteria, being opportunistic, will use the chance to multiply and become a problem, so there we have an example of a bacteria that's beneficial, but can become a problem if not kept in check).